# Slicing data in a crossfilter object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a situation where the crossfilter data set is large, in the order of 2000 rows. Rendering the crossfilter data on a D3 graph takes a bit of time, especially on an older computer and mobile tablet. Is there any way to slice the crossfilter data so that the D3 graph can then incrementally render the crossfilter data on the UI? The crossfilter object is already loaded with data, by the time the call is made to the dc.js rendering object - as in this pseudo code -

```
    var cfGroup, cfDim; 
    init: function()
    {
        var ndxObj = crossfilter(incomingData);
        cfDim = ndxObj.dimension(//pick a dimension);
        cfGroup = cfDim.group(){//group function};
        var sliderChart = dc.barChart("#lineslider-id");

    }
    // this function is called every time the page is loaded or switched to
    renderChart : function()
    {
        // How do I slice the CF object and call redraw() successively?
        sliderChart.width(20).height(40).dimension(cfDim).group(cfGroup);
        sliderChart.redraw();
    }
```

Comment: Question: In your renderChart function, why do you reset the dimension() and group() accessors on your sliderChart? Why not just redraw()?

Comment: I agree that these accessors are not needed. I'll remove the dimension() and group() accessors in the sliderChart renderChart function. Do you think this contributes to hit to performance?

Comment: Not sure, but I wouldn't be surprised. I think it's probably forcing dc.js to completely recalculate the chart when all it needs to do is an update.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use

```
crossfilter.add(records)
```

to add records from your data set incrementally.

see https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_add